# Behavior for displaying map doesn't run

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to create a pretty straightforward page with a Google map that I need to customize, but the code in the behavior isn't being run for some reason. Here's the code:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_theme
 */
function mymodule_theme() {
  return array(
    'affiliates_map' => array(
      'template' => 'affiliates-map',
      'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/templates',
      'render element' => 'content',
     )
  );
}

/*
 * Page callback for map page.
 */
function mymodule_search_map() {
  drupal_add_css('
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }', array('group' => CSS_DEFAULT, 'type' => 'inline'));

  $path = drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule');
  $gmap_api_key = variable_get('affiliates_gmap_api_key', '');
  drupal_add_js('//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=' . $gmap_api_key . '&callback=initMap',  array('type' => 'external'));
  drupal_add_js($path . '/js/mymodule.js', array('type' => 'file', 'weight' => 6, 'scope' => 'footer'));

  $output = theme('affiliates_map');

  return $output;
}
```

Here's my theme template.

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 *   This template handles the display of the affiliates map.
 */
?>

<h2>Map content goes here</h2>

<div id="naa-map"></div>
```

and the js file

```
(function($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.affiliatesMap = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      var map;

      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('naa-map'), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 14
        });
      }
    }
  };
}(jQuery));
```

My console is giving me an error about initMap() not being found, and when I put a breakpoint in the behavior in initMap, it doesn't get hit. What am I doing wrong that it's not finding the behavior code? I've mimicked the [Location Map](https://drupal.org/project/locationmap) module, and it works fine, so I'm not sure where I went wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The issue ended up being my CSS. I was using styles from the sample page that had a height of 100%. Once I added some height and width to my naa-map div, my map showed up fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not declare initMap inside of the anonymous attachment - cause it's not visible outsinde. Try it like

```
(function($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.affiliatesMap = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      function initMap();

    }
  };
}(jQuery));

var map;

function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('naa-map'), {
      center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
      zoom: 14
    });
}
```

But I think it's anyway not so nice with that global space "var map".